# Visual Studio 2019 is missing the Add Page options dialog for Partial View & Generate PageModel?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio **2017**, when I add a new Razor Page to my project, this dialog box opens:

[image]

However, in Visual Studio **2019**, this is the final screen I see before the page is added to my project:

[image]

This is very annoying because I don't have the options of setting it as a partial view or to not generate the PageModel class. I've searched around and haven't found anyone with this same problem. I'm using the Community edition of Visual Studio for both 2017 and 2019.

Comment: Just click okay and put your partial view code in it and remove the page route. It would be treated as a partial view. Those options just give you a template, there's no marker on those files that determines the kind of cshtml files they are, what you put inside the file determines it.

Comment: @Qudus Right and that's what I've had to do. Since 2017 has these template options it surprised me that 2019 doesn't offer them. I was hoping there was a feature I need to add or an option I need to turn on? It's just strange that this screen would be removed from 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Sequel to my comment, if you still want to have the view as you do in VS 2017. Right click on your view folder, click `Add` then `View`. There are two options on this page `Razor View - Empty` and `Razor View`. Click on `Razor View` and then click `Add`. You should see the page.

Comment: This is correct and I'm seeing both options for `Razor View` and `Razor View - Empty`. However, for razor pages the only options I have are `Razor Page - Empty`, `Razor Page using EF` and `Razor Page using EF (CRUD)`. There isn't an option for just `Razor Page`. I checked 2017 and it is there.

Comment: I never used VS2017, but I guess the dynamics changed. So, even you are on razor pages, you have to use Razor View - Empty or delete the page model if you don't want a page model. I'm not sure they provided just razor page view

Comment: This silly behaviour is the same in VS2022. I've no idea why they changed it but now when I select `Razor View` (rather than `Razor View - Empty`, as you suggested, even though it makes no sense) and then specify a partial view with no model, it takes VS several seconds, with a progress bar talking about scaffolding and building the project. Complete overkill when there's no model involved. This used to be quick and simple.